# How I can update my objects in template dynamically?

Tags: python, django

I have comments on a product on the page. and there is a button to add a comment, which puts a new comment into the database. How can I automatically display a new comment on a page?

**mytemplate.html**

```
<div id="comments">
{% include 'comments.html' %}
</div>
```

**comments.html**

```
{% for comment in comments %}
        <!-- some code for display comments -->
{% endfor %}
```

**script.js**

```
$("#addComment").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        if ($("#addCommentArea").val() != ""){
            data = {
                commentText: $("#addCommentArea").val(),
                product_id: "{{ product.id }}"
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'newcomment' %}",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#addCommentArea").val("")
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

**views.py**

```
class CommentView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        commentText = request.GET.get("commentText")
        if (len(commentText) > 0):
            newComment = Comment()
            newComment.Author = request.user
            product_id = request.GET.get("product_id")
            product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
            newComment.Product = product
            newComment.Comment = commentText
            newComment.save()
        return JsonResponse({'ok': 'ok'})
```

Comment: It will be useful if you can include your view responding to `{% url 'newcomment' %}`url to see it's current response.

Comment: include the view

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you just render the template once and fetch the comments, further you are using Ajax to submit, which means your template doesn't get updated. To update the comments without a page refresh you can either make a javascript polling or use for example web sockets